# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sec.enterprise.knox.keystore.TimaKeystore

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I use `WebView` in a `ScrollView`. what will happend if I ignore this  Exception?

**here is the log:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sec.enterprise.knox.keystore.TimaKeystore
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyStore.getDefaultType(KeyStore.java:212)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.net.X509Util.ensureInitialized(X509Util.java:109)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.net.X509Util.verifyServerCertificates(X509Util.java:242)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.net.AndroidNetworkLibrary.verifyServerCertificates(AndroidNetworkLibrary.java:210)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sec/enterprise/knox/keystore/TimaKeystore
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:  ... 8 more
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sec.enterprise.knox.keystore.TimaKeystore" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-25 16:58:47.340 21874-22149/com.shengzhebj.driver W/System.err:  ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the excpetion says. You miss the required libraray in your classpath.

[Download](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/knox/0.8.0/knox-0.8.0.zip) it and put it into your classpath.

For more Information the the official [documentation](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-8-0/user-guide.html)